# Heroku Django app not serving, crashing because ModuleNotFoundError:<app> (*not a requirements module*)?

Tags: python, django, heroku

So i have an existing Django project (called 'MLshowcase') i have built over the last several months. I am trying to deploy to Heroku for the first time, have followed all the steps and added all the files I think i need. After about 50 failures (requirements too big) i finally got the project to deploy! One note: i did have to disable collectstatic on heroku in order to deploy, otherwise it kept saying one of my static files "was not in the root 'static'". but it did deploy.

However, going to the application (called 'iansworld' on heroku) just shows "application error, page could not be served". I have been fiddling with the settings and wsgi for a day now and still nothing. When i look into Herko logs, it appears it goes build-crash-build-crash-build-crash..etc with several of the logs saying:

```
app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'iansworld'
```

full github: [here](https://github.com/CourseCharter/MLshowcase)

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn iansworld.wsgi --log-file -
```

requirements.txt

```
conda==4.3.16
conda-build==2.1.5
decorator==4.4.1
django==3.0.3
django-heroku
djangorestframework==3.9.3
django-crispy-forms==1.9.1
dj_database_url
django-adminlte-3==0.1.6
gunicorn
html5lib==1.0.1
joblib==0.14.1
json5==0.9.1
jsonschema==3.2.0
matplotlib==3.1.3
numpy==1.18.1
packaging==19.1
pandas==1.0.1
path==13.1.0
requests==2.22.0
scikit-learn==0.22.1
scipy==1.4.1
seaborn==0.10.0
tables==3.6.1
whitenoise
```

settings.py

```
import os
import dj_database_url
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"staticfiles")
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY", "xxx")

# SECURITY WARNING: don"t run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.environ.get("DJANGO_DEBUG", "") != "False"

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["iansword.herokuapp.com", "localhost", "127.0.0.1"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",
    "adminlte3",
    "adminlte3_theme",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "titanic",
    "rest_framework",
    "crispy_forms",
    "skills",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",

]

ROOT_URLCONF = "mlshowcase.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "mlshowcase.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"),
    }
}

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES["default"].update(db_from_env)

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"

#LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser",
        "rest_framework.parsers.FormParser",
    )
}

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap4"
```

I have collectstatic locally so i have a 'static' and 'staticfiles' in the root. i was able to serve locally prior to successful deployment. so must be a config issue right?

here is the heroku log --tail:

```
20-05-20T00:39:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user XX
2020-05-20T00:42:25.148602+00:00 app[api]: Release v14 created by user XX
2020-05-20T00:42:25.148602+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 5c85f4db by user XX
2020-05-20T00:42:26.539576+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-20T00:42:50.929018+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-20T00:42:50.701801+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 00:42:50 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-05-20T00:42:50.702751+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 00:42:50 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:29801 (4)
2020-05-20T00:42:50.703003+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 00:42:50 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-05-20T00:42:50.711275+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 00:42:50 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718832+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 00:42:50 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718834+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718834+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718835+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718835+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718836+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718836+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718836+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718837+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718837+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718838+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718838+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718839+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718839+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718839+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718840+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718840+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718841+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718841+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718842+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718842+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718842+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718843+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718843+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718844+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-05-20T00:42:50.718844+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'iansworld'
2020-05-20T00:42:50.719216+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 00:42:50 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-05-20T00:42:50.765012+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 00:42:50 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-05-20T00:42:50.765168+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 00:42:50 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-05-20T00:42:58.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-20T00:45:00.448059+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-20T00:45:32.080224+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-20T00:45:31.890218+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 00:45:31 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-05-20T00:45:31.891181+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 00:45:31 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:18844 (4)
2020-05-20T00:45:31.891401+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 00:45:31 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-05-20T00:45:31.897725+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 00:45:31 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906592+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 00:45:31 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906594+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906608+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906610+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906610+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906610+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906611+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906611+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906612+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906612+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906612+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906613+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906613+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906614+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906614+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906614+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906615+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906615+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906616+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906616+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906617+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906617+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906617+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906618+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906618+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906618+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'iansworld'
2020-05-20T00:45:31.906935+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 00:45:31 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-05-20T00:45:31.950987+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 00:45:31 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-05-20T00:45:31.951221+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-20 00:45:31 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-05-20T00:45:41.382497+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=iansworld.herokuapp.com request_id=c5196195-eeea-4cd4-a142-665a7f0e7bc0 fwd="193.176.211.52" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

in the logs i also see the protocol is https, but my app does not have https yet. not sure if that might  be an issue as well? Its really difficult to troubleshoot becuase herokus documentation pretends that everything works on the fist try..

Help is greatly appreciated as i have spent about 15 hours trying to deploy to heroku laready and i think i am at my troubleshooting limit :)